# jQuery $.parseJSON data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i use $.parseJSON to get data from a link.

My output link have

```
{"status":"ok", "message":'<form><input type="text" name="" value=""> </form>'}
```

And i want to append the "message" to my content.

```
$.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "mylinl.php",
                    data : reservationForm.serialize(),
                    success : function(result) {

                        var data = $.parseJSON(result);

                        var result = data.status;
                        var message = data.message;

                        if (result == 'ok') {

                          $('#mycontent').html(message);

                        } else {

                          alert('Error Message: ' + message);
                        }
                    },
```

So i want to get the message : `<form><input type="text" name="" value=""> </form>` from my link and ouput to my #mycontent. is that possible?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: you have to have double quotes and not single quotes around the `<form>...</form>` part

Comment: @MichaelKunst yes, but i want to use also double quotes inside my `<input name="somename">` tag

Comment: @Mando Madalin are you tried this? then what's the result???

Comment: escape them: `{"status":"ok", "message":"<form><input type=\"text\" name=\"\" value=\"\"> </form>"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside your code, escape the doubble qoutes like this:

```
{"status":"ok", "message":"<form><input type=\"text\" name=\"\" value=\"\"> </form>"}
```

Comment: form is still not in double quotes, change that ;)